# Why wont this taylor-series give a result for numbers >= 1

Tags: java, trigonometry, taylor-series

I am building my own function for calculating the Cosinus as a Taylor-series.
Unfortunately the Code wont execute for numbers > 1.
There are many other examples for this problem I know, but for my own java-knowledge I would like to know what is the problem.

```
public class Cosinus {

    public static double cos(double x) {
        double sum = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; i++) {
            double summand = (Math.pow(x, 2 * i) / fak(2 * i)) * Math.pow((-1), i);

            if (Math.abs(summand) >= 0.001) {
                sum += summand;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return sum; 
    }

    private static double fak(int i) {
        int ergebnis = 1;

        for (int count = 1; count <= i; count++) {
            ergebnis = count * ergebnis;
        }

        return ergebnis;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(cos(10.0));  
    }
}
```

Comment: "wont execute" in what way? And are you intending to calculate cos(10 radians), or cos(10 degrees)?

Comment: `fak(int i)` would give you incorrect results even for small values of i (due to int overflow). Try changing `ergebnis` to double.

Comment: changing i to double was the solution for my problem . Thank you very much.

Comment: Or avoid explicitly computing factorials at all.  Instead, compute each term from the previous one by multiplying by `-x * x` and dividing by `2 * ((2 * i * i) - i)`.